# How to change File name rquested url in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup Nginx for serving images, If nginx receives the request:

```
http://<serverip>/images/image_name.jpeg
```

If this file does not exist then I want to serve the different basic image, like:

```
http://<serverip>/images/image_name_base.jpeg
```

I'm stuck here as I am new to nginx.

Can anyone tell me how we can achieve this ?

Comment: You could try reading the documentation of nginx or searching the web for tutorials. The keywords to search for are "nginx url rewriting"

Comment: So you want to add `_base` suffix?